# Confused as to How I should Interpret the Exponential Distribution and its Probability Density Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution

I'm confused as to how I should be interpreting the exponential distribution and its probability density function (PDF). I'm specifically referring to the fact that it peaks close to $x = 0$ and then tapers off.

Does the PDF of an exponential distribution indicate that (some type of) machinery is MOST likely to fail immediately after it is built? In other words, does it indicate that the probability of failure is highest right after the machinery has been built? This doesn't seem to intuitively be correct, since machinery should have the least chance of failure if it is brand new, right? This makes me suspect that I'm misunderstand something.

**Example #1:**

[image]

**Example #2:**

[image]

**Example #3:**

[image]

Take examples #2 and #3. Example #2 has had the PDF superimposed on top of it. Since the PDF is largest close to $x = 0$, how do I interpret this? If I compare it to example #3, then it would be saying that the probability is highest that the time to failure is small -- somewhere between 0-80? But that would mean that the machinery is most likely to fail soon after it is brand new! And so it doesn't seem to make intuitive sense.

I'm very confused as to how I should be interpreting this, and I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify.

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as "breaking as soon as it is built", you could think of it as being unlikely to "survive" the older it gets. Of course, this is just a simplified probabilistic model, and something more realistic would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: @JohnDoe So are you saying that I should interpret the PDF as indicating the probability that it survives until a certain time?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. A possible explanation for this could be: the probability that some bug or fault has happened in the time between its manufacturing time and now is much higher for a large time than if we chose a small time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second graph is wrong in that it shows a vertical tangent at $\text{time}=0.$

An exponential distribution is the right model only if the **conditional** probability of failure on the $n\text{th}$ day **given** that it has survived until then, is the *same* as the probability of failure on the first day.

However, that implies that failure on the $n\text{th}$ day is less probable than failure on the first day (if $n>1$) *only* because of the possibility that the machine already failed *before* the $n$th day.

Comment: So the exponential distribution DOES say that the probability of failure is highest close to $x = 0$, given that it has survived until then? So the machinery would be most likely to fail early on. But the probability of failure farther out is low given the probability that failure would have probably ALREADY occurred before then? So the machinery, if it lasts till some period farther out on the curve, is JUST as likely to fail as it was at any other period (memorylessness), but the fact that it would have most likely ALREADY at an earlier point means that the ...

Comment: probability of any piece of machinery failing at this later period is low?

Comment: To use example #2, the probability of failure for a piece of machinery is highest during the early period from 0-80. BUT, if the piece of machinery lasts till 240, it lasting till 240 still has a low probability of happening because of the probability that it would have failed before 240? Although, at 240 it would still have the same probability of failure as at 0-80 (due to memorylessness).

Comment: Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: @ThePointer : I think you've got it now.

Comment: Excellent! It's taken so long, but I think I finally have the correct intuition. Thank you so much for the assistance!!! :)